# Can't add the last element in the list in python

Tags: python

```
def front_x(words):
list2 = []
for word in words:
    if word[0] == 'x':
        list2.append(word)
        words.remove(word)
words.sort()
list2.sort()

return list2 + words




def main():
    print(front_x(['bbb', 'ccc', 'axx', 'xzz', 'xaa']))




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is my code I'm trying to do this example:

Given a list of strings, return the count of the number of
strings where the string length is 2 or more and the first
and last chars of the string are the same.
Note: python does not have a ++ operator, but += works.

and the output is like this : ['xzz', 'axx', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'xaa']

The problem is the last element on the list don't go to the new list I created. What should I do?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "The problem is the last element on the list don't go to the new list I created"

Comment: [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module may be useful here.

Comment: isn't this code work totally differnet from prblem statement?

Comment: Do not delete its elements during the iteration.
You can modify `for word in words.copy()` as follows.

Answer (score 2):

- You shouldn't change the `words` when you are iterating through it, otherwise it'll lead to some bugs. You need iterate the copy of `words` to avoid changing it.
- You remove the words when `word[0] == 'x'`, which cause the loop end before you want.
- You can use debug mode in IDE(such as `VSCode`, `PyCharm`) to run your code line by line to check what actually happened in runtime.

#### example code:

```
def front_x(words):
    list2 = []
    for word in words.copy():
        if word[0] == 'x':
            list2.append(word)
            words.remove(word)
    words.sort()
    list2.sort()

    return list2 + words

def main():
    print(front_x(['bbb', 'ccc', 'axx', 'xzz', 'xaa']))

main()
```

#### result:

```
['xaa', 'xzz', 'axx', 'bbb', 'ccc']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are removing the element from the same list you are iterating . After removing an element from list , element position shift. When iteration pointer is on second last element list changes from ['bbb', 'ccc', 'axx', 'xzz', 'xaa'] to
['bbb', 'ccc', 'axx', 'xaa']. Thus iteration pointer now points to last element .

Answer (score -2):

In this problem the question wants you to use 2 different things:

1. `len` function
2. list indexing

### `len`

`len` returns the size of a container. A container can be a `str`, `list`, `tuple`, etc.

To check if the length of the given string is equal or bigger then 2.

```
if len(word) >= 2:
```

### indexing

Accessing the first element of a container (in your example a string) is easy. You can get the `0th` element like:

```
word[0]
```

But you will need to get the last element of a container and your strings can change in length. So you must come with a method to get the last element of the container.

You, again, can use the `len` function. like:

```
last_char = word[len(word) - 1]
```

or you can use [negative indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/2681662).

```
last_char = word[-1]
```